# Write multiple describeBy summaries to individual worksheets in an Excel workbook using openxlsx

Tags: r, psych, openxlsx, describe

I have a large data frame that I summarize in multiple ways using `describeBy` from the `psych` library as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(psych)
.
.
.
 # Describe by Region
  lst1 <- describeBy(df[QUESTIONS], df[REGION_DESCRIPTOR])

  # Describe by Doctor
  lst2 <- describeBy(df[QUESTIONS], df[CARE_DESCRIPTOR])
```

I then create a new workbook

```
  wb = createWorkbook()
```

and start trying to write lst1, lst2,.... into into it, one item per worksheet:

```
  addWorksheet(wb, REGION_DESCRIPTOR)
  writeData(wb, REGION_DESCRIPTOR, lst1)

  addWorksheet(wb, CARE_DESCRIPTOR)
  writeData(wb, CARE_DESCRIPTOR, lst2)
```

Unfortunately, I get an error message:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("psych", "describeBy")’ to a data.frame
```

How can I write each `describeBy` object to a worksheet using `openxlsx`? I have tried using `writexl`, and while it works, I am not happy with the fact that it writes each of the summmaries generated by `describeBy` to a different worksheet. As I have close to a dozen `describeBy`'s, each with 3-5 categories, this rapidly becomes unwieldy.

Thank you in advance for your help

Thomas Philips

Comment: Could you please paste the output of `dput(df)` in the question in order to help you!

Comment: Can you try with `do.call(rbind, describeBy(mtcars[, 'mpg'], mtcars[, 'vs']) )`

Comment: Try to change to data structure from "psych" and "describeBy" to something more standard, like a data frame, before you try to write it/save it.

Comment: The output of dput(lst1) is too long to print, but it starts and ends like this: `> dput(lst1)
structure(list(ASIA_HIGH_INCOME = structure(list(vars = 1:17, 
    n = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), ..., row.names = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", 
    "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", 
    "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17"))), .Dim = 10L, .Dimnames = list(
    Region = c("ASIA_HIGH_INCOME", "ASIA_MIDDLE_INCOME", ..., "WESTERN_EUROPE")), call = by.data.frame(data = x, 
    INDICES = group, FUN = describe, type = type), class = c("psych", 
"describeBy"))`

Answer (score 1):

The object output from `describeBy` is a `list`.  We could `rbind` them to a single matrix or data.frame and it should work

```
do.call(rbind, describeBy(mtcars[, 'mpg'], mtcars[, 'vs']) )
```

Comment: 'do.call(rbind, describeBy(df[QUESTIONS, REGION_DESCRIPTOR], df[QUESTIONS, CARE_DESCRIPTOR]))
Error in do.call(rbind, describeBy(df[QUESTIONS, REGION_DESCRIPTOR], df[QUESTIONS,  : 
  second argument must be a list`

Comment: @ThomasPhilips The example I showed works for me.  Your example is not reproducible to test

Comment: Your example does indeed work. Each of the describeBy's generates a single column, which can then be glued together with rbind. in my case, I am applying describeBy to 17 questions for each of the descriptors.

Comment: @ThomasPhilips You meant mulitple groups ?

Comment: Perhaps i should start with a simpler question: how can i write a single describeBy applied to 17 questions to a worksheet. I'm having difficulty creating a MWE because the problem is large

Comment: Perhaps you meant `do.call(rbind, describeBy(mtcars[c('disp','mpg')], mtcars[, 'vs']))`, it is working for me as well.  The 'disp', 'mpg' corresponds to the 'Questions' columns in your case

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks a mill. I haven't ever used do.call, but will read up on it Thanks again!

Comment: @ThomasPhilips Thanks, but why you got error earlier

Comment: @ThomasPhilips if there are more than column, you need to concatenate i.e. `do.call(rbind, describeBy(mtcars[c('disp','mpg')], mtcars[c('vs', 'gear')]))`